# Regular expression with a lookahead doesn't work like I expect

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have a regular expression. Its behavior isn't like I would expect. I have a lookahead. I expect to match in the example in the code returning an array that contains the string`a12-` rather `null` is returned. Can anyone explain to me why?

```js
let reg=/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+(?=1)$/; //equal to /^(\w|-)+(?=1)$/
console.log(reg.exec('a12-1'));
```

Comment: Did you mean to put the `$` anchor inside the lookahead? A non-empty lookahead behind the end of the input will never match.

Comment: I understand you just want to make sure there is `1` at the end of the string, right? `/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)1$/`? Like, ``/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)1$/.exec('a12-1')[1]``?

Comment: @Bergi The `$` is a metacharacter here. I would capture something only if it ends with `1` without capture the `1`. I would expect that my regular expression works

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I understood now your solution using a capturing group.  But I still don't understand why my initial solution doesn't work

Comment: @Umbert `$` captures no input, it only matches at that point or not. Just like a lookahead does. And no, your regex doesn't express "followed by (1 after which it ends)", but "is followed by 1, and ends immediately"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not work because you require `1` to appear after the end of string. `(?=1)$` means *end of string* immediately after which there must be `1`. Note that both the positive lookahead and the `$` anchor are *zero-width assertions* that do not move the regex index (when the patterns are tried, the regex index remains at the same position) and the text they match (here, only the lookahead has a char to match) does not get appended to the overall match value. So, both are executed at the end of string.

You can use

```js
/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)1$/.exec('a12-1')[1]
/^([\w-]*)1$/.exec('a12-1')[1]
```

**NOTE**: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` = `\w` in JavaScript regex.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([\w-]*)` - Capturing group 1: zero or more word or `-` chars
- `1` - a `1` char
- `$` - end of string

```js
console.log(/^([\w-]*)1$/.exec('a12-1')[1])
```